# my sql command within codeigniter is not working

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, records

I tested this function but it doesn't work and no query result produced. What's wrong Im newbie. Is there any AR alternatives? Im trying to create a mini search engine. Thanks so much in advance.

```
function search($terms)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM products 
          WHERE name LIKE '%$terms%' 
            OR image LIKE '%$terms%' 
            OR code LIKE '%$terms'");
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($terms, $terms));
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: please fix the display of your code, indent w/ 4 spaces.

Comment: Please post the value of `$terms` and the contents of a record which you think should be returned.

Comment: Note that the last line of your query is inconsistent: `OR code LIKE '%$terms'"` maybe you meant to write: `OR code LIKE '%$terms%'"` ?

Answer (score 0):

To bind your query with the data passed to the function, you have to do the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products 
          WHERE name LIKE ? 
            OR image LIKE ?
            OR code LIKE ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array($terms,$terms,$terms));
```

Also in our posted code, remove the extra parenthesis from string $sql and you are binding only two values, when the query requires 3

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products 
          WHERE name LIKE ? 
            OR image LIKE ?
            OR code LIKE ?";
$this->db->like('name', $terms);
$this->db->like('image', $terms);
$this->db->like('code', $terms);
$query=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: I think we still need the wildcard characters. `OR image LIKE %?%`

Comment: here is another great link which suggest how to work with wildcard characters: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: The link you provided is for Active Record docs, it doesn't mention how to use wildcards with query bindings using the `query()` function.

Comment: if you scroll down to the middle of the page, it does. Search for "$this->db->or_like()" in that page

Comment: You've missed my point entirely. `or_like()` is not the same as using `query()` on an SQL string - and you cannot combine them. The `$sql` variable in your second example does nothing.